# meter.value update works but doesn't update "hover" value shown

Tags: javascript, html

If I use javascript to update a meter's value it works:

```
var LFRMSMeter = document.getElementById("LFRMSMeter");
LFRMSMeter.value = parseFloat(j[0]);
```

So that is good but when I "hover" over the meter the tooltip shows the orginal value in the html, not the updated by javascript value.

This seems to be true for both chrome and firefox.

How can I get the tooltip to show the javascript updated value?

Here's the html:

```
<meter id="LFRMSMeter"  min=-60 max=10 low=-33 high=-3 optimum=-20  value=0>LFRMSMeter</meter>
```

After javascript the update the meter changes but the tooltip still says zero.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using the `.title` property of the element...

```
var LFRMSMeter = document.getElementById("LFRMSMeter");
LFRMSMeter.value = parseFloat(j[0]);
LFRMSMeter.title = parseFloat(j[0]);
```

[Live JSFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/sJek5/)

Comment: You're welcome, @user2981769. Please remember to mark my answer as correct, so the community knows that your issue has been sorted.